# SFML title bar with weird characters when using UTF-8

Tags: c++, utf-8, sfml

I've just started using SFML and one of the first problems I've come across is some weird characters on the the titlebar whenever I try to use accents or any other extended char.

For instance, I've got:

```
sf::RenderWindow Ventana(sf::VideoMode(800, 600, 32), "Año nuevóóó");
```

And the titlebar renders like `AÂ+o nuevoA³A³A³`

This ONLY HAPPENS if my source code file is enconded in UTF-8. If I change the file encoding to ISO-8859-1, it shows properly. Obviously all of my files use UTF-8, as its the system-wide encoding.

I've tried using the different utilities in `sf::Unicode` to adapt the text, but none of them seems to work.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? It sounds like it's not properly detecting the encoding.

Comment: I'm using GCC under Ubuntu GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess, you are using VC++ with SFML2? and your project is compiling in debug mode with the dynamic SFML release libraries? It is a known issue that debug and release modes can cause issues with SFML 2.0. Make sure you are linking to the debug libraries.

Here is the post of a person who had a problem that sounds similar to yours.

http://www.sfml-dev.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5412&highlight=corrupted+title

Comment: You should read the comments. I _was_ using GCC under Ubuntu GNU/Linux. Actually I dropped all effort in trying to make it work.

Comment: Apologies, I should have read the comments. Best of luck with your future SFML endeavours, if this hasn't turned you off it :)